# How to select a class of div inside of a div with beautiful soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a bunch of div tags within div tags:

```
<div class="foo">
     <div class="bar">I want this</div>
     <div class="unwanted">Not this</div>
</div>
<div class="bar">Don't want this either
</div>
```

So I'm using python and beautiful soup to separate stuff out. I need all the "bar" class only when it is wrapped inside of a "foo" class div. Here's my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(r'C:\test.htm'))
tag = soup.div
for each_div in soup.findAll('div',{'class':'foo'}):
    print(tag["bar"]).encode("utf-8")
```

Alternately, I tried:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(r'C:\test.htm'))
for each_div in soup.findAll('div',{'class':'foo'}):
     print(each_div.findAll('div',{'class':'bar'})).encode("utf-8")
```

What am I doing wrong? I would be just as happy with just a simple print(each_div) if I could remove the div class "unwanted" from the selection.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `find_all()` to search every `<div>` elements with `foo` as attribute and for each one of them use `find()` for those with `bar` as attribute, like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys 

soup = BeautifulSoup(open(sys.argv[1], 'r'), 'html')
for foo in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'foo'}):
    bar = foo.find('div', attrs={'class': 'bar'})
    print(bar.text)
```

Run it like:

```
python3 script.py htmlfile
```

That yields:

```
I want this
```

---

**UPDATE**: Assuming there could exists several `<div>` elements with `bar` attribute, previous script won't work. It will only find the first one. But you could get their descendants and iterate them, like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys 

soup = BeautifulSoup(open(sys.argv[1], 'r'), 'html')
for foo in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'foo'}):
    foo_descendants = foo.descendants
    for d in foo_descendants:
        if d.name == 'div' and d.get('class', '') == ['bar']:
            print(d.text)
```

With an input like:

```
<div class="foo">
     <div class="bar">I want this</div>
     <div class="unwanted">Not this</div>
     <div class="bar">Also want this</div>
</div>
```

It will yield:

```
I want this
Also want this
```