# How to scrape a line of text which is under a <div> tag which is in turn under a <div class> tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
<div class="style__font-bold___1k9Dl style__font-14px___YZZrf style__flex-row___2AKyf style__space-between___2mbvn style__padding-bottom-5px___2NrDR">
    <div>Augmentin 625 Duo Tablet</div></div>
```

I want to scrape the "Augmentin 625 Duo Tablet" text but can't seem to get it.

The code I am using right now:

```
import requests
import bs4
import lxml

result=requests.get("https://www.pharmadude.com")

#print((type(result)))


soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(result.text,"lxml")

#print(soup)

scrape=soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'style__font-bold___1k9Dl style__font-14px___YZZrf style__flex-row___2AKyf style__space-between___2mbvn style__padding-bottom-5px___2NrDR'})
for div in scrape:
    bar=soup.find_all('div')
    print(bar.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
import bs4
import lxml

result=requests.get("https://www.1mg.com/drugs-all-medicines")

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(result.text,"lxml")

box = soup.find('a', attrs={"href": "/drugs/augmentin-625-duo-tablet-138629"})
text_content = box.find('span')
for paragraph in text_content.find_all('p'):
      print(paragraph.text)
price = text_content.find('div').find('span').text
print(price)
```

Output:

```
Augmentin 625 Duo Tablet
Prescription Required
strip of 10 tablets
Glaxo SmithKline Pharmaceuticals Ltd
Amoxycillin  (500mg) +  Clavulanic Acid (125mg)
MRP ₹200.59
```

First, identify the box containing your data. Then get the span with the text in it. For each paragraph within the span, print the text.

If interested in the price, go into the div and further into it's span.

Answer (score 1):

You use `find_all` to define `bar`. So `bar` is a list and has not a `text` property. Instead of `find_all`, use `find` on `div` variable of your loop. Like that:

```py
import requests
import bs4
import lxml

result=requests.get("https://www.1mg.com/drugs-all-medicines")

#print((type(result)))

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(result.text,"lxml")

#print(soup)

scrape=soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'style__font-bold___1k9Dl style__font-14px___YZZrf style__flex-row___2AKyf style__space-between___2mbvn style__padding-bottom-5px___2NrDR'})
for div in scrape:
    bar=div.find('div')
    print(bar.text)
```

(you can also refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22217852/13123142))

Comment: thank you for the answer ...but even when i run it now there is no output...i am writing the code on sublime text and running on git bash

Comment: print something in the loop to know if the loop is triggered. are you sure that the classes you select is present in the HTML code?

Comment: thank you arthur your answer was right....im a noob in terms of web scrapping and i realised the code wont work cause the classes i selected isnt in the html code ....i thought that the code in inspect and page source would always be the same but it seems like that aint the case ...thank you anyways

Comment: no problem ;), everyone has been like you, at the beginning.

Answer (score -1):

```
import requests
import bs4
import lxml

result=requests.get("https://www.1mg.com/drugs-all-medicines")

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(result.text,"lxml")

scrape=soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'style__font-bold___1k9Dl style__font-14px___YZZrf style__flex-row___2AKyf style__space-between___2mbvn style__padding-bottom-5px___2NrDR'})

bar = soup.find_all('div')[1].text
print(bar)
```

Output: `Augmentin 625 Duo Tablet`

This code is exactly what you need.

`soup.find_all` returns a list, you need to find the item in the list and then get the `.text` property of that item. In your case the item is the second item, hence using the first index.